# Im trying to sit images next to each-other HTML and CSS using figcaption with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add buttons underneath my images on my webpage, so I decided to use figcaption tag to insert buttons under each image. However, when I do this the images stack on top of each other and not side by side as they normally are.

```
**My HTML:**

    <section class="mostpurch">    
  <h1> Latest PC downloads... </h1>
    <p> Most purchased on PC </p>
    <img src="images/fallout-4.jpg" class="f41" />
    <figcaption><button type="button">Add to basket</button></figcaption>
    <img src="images/Tom-Clancys-The-Division.jpg" class="tctd1" />
    <figcaption><button type="button">Add to basket</button></figcaption>
    <img src="images/blops3.jpg" class="blops31" />
    <figcaption><button type="button">Add to basket</button></figcaption>
    <img src="images/acsyn.jpg" class="acsyn1" />
    <figcaption><button type="button">Add to basket</button></figcaption> 
  </section>
```

Im not sure what I have to do in my HTML or CSS to make it possible. 
[How it currently is (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAbIt.png)

I want toit to sit next to each other with buttons underneath. Sorry if there is a better way of doing this I am new to this.

Thanks in advanced

-Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is put each `<img>` and `<figcaption>` inside a containing div, then add CSS to the container: `display: inline-block`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/527fky5z/)

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="mostpurch">
  <h1> Latest PC downloads... </h1>
  <p>Most purchased on PC</p>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/10cd84d9efcfd5b5d800bcd92694a5a3?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="f41" />
    <figcaption>
      <button type="button">Add to basket</button>
    </figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/10cd84d9efcfd5b5d800bcd92694a5a3?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="f41" />
    <figcaption>
      <button type="button">Add to basket</button>
    </figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/10cd84d9efcfd5b5d800bcd92694a5a3?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="f41" />
    <figcaption>
      <button type="button">Add to basket</button>
    </figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/10cd84d9efcfd5b5d800bcd92694a5a3?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="f41" />
    <figcaption>
      <button type="button">Add to basket</button>
    </figcaption>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said but they seemed to form a strange shape, with two images being on top, one in the centre and then one at the bottom and all the sizes changed.

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: It is working for me, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/527fky5z/). I edited the above answer to have code snippet. It works fine. Post a fiddle of what is happening when you do it.

Comment: When I test just that section of the code in JSFiddle is works. It must be something to do with the contents of my page, though I cannot figure it out. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I have figured it out now, thanks for the CSS that made it work. It was to do with the sizes of my images in the CSS. I adjusted them and now it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<section class="mostpurch">    
  <h1> Latest PC downloads... </h1>
    <p> Most purchased on PC </p>
    <div>
      <img src="images/fallout-4.jpg" class="f41" />
      <figcaption><button type="button">Add to basket</button></figcaption>
    </div>  
</section>
```

**css**

`div{display: inline;}`

Comment: Please explain your answers and why they should work